# What qualities of the Gormenghast series have made it such a critical success?

Tags: gormenghast, mervyn-peake

Mervyn Peake's Gormenghast series of fantasy novels have attracted enormous literary and critical praise. It has made numerous "top X fantasy" lists, been suggested as required secondary school reading and been called a classic by esteemed authors such as Antony Burgess and Harold Bloom.

A surface reading, however, might find little to justify such praise. The descriptive language is impressive, but sometimes overwrought. Even wikipedia can list no further underlying themes beyond a fairly obvious examination of the clash between freedom and tradition.

Much of the praise has been directed at Gormenghast as a work of imagination. However the modern reader, used to several decades of fantasy being a popular, rich and prolific genre, might find it difficult to place in the context of having been written in the 40's and 50's.

Questions over why the book was a critical success but a commercial failure, especially compared with the publication of The Lord of the Rings in the 50's, have haunted it since publication. Even its fans seem to find these questions difficult to answer. For instance here, [a journalist simply dismisses them with the answer that the book is "too good" for commercial success and was perhaps a little before its time](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2014/aug/16/gormenghast-masterpiece-mervyn-peake).

Was the series uniquely influential and imaginative in the fantasy genre at time of publication? If not, what else about it excites such adulation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this seems quite opinion based.

Comment: Notwithstanding Mith's comment, I think this is an interesting question and one which could potentially be answered based on objective evidence, e.g. reviews or analysis or expert knowledge of that period in English literature. I voted to undelete it years ago, before being a mod, and now a couple of others have cast the remaining undelete votes.